# How to import an entire module from within the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything for this specific topic. So here's the question:

In python 3 when you want to import an object from some module you would write something like

```
from module import object
```

If you want to specify that the module is in the same diretory as the file you're currently working on, you'd precede the module name with a dot like

```
from .module import object
```

What do I have to write in order to import an entire module from within the same directory? Intuitively, I tried

```
import .module
```

But this gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way is to import the module *from* the current package, i.e. `.`.

```
from . import module
```

This makes the module available with the name `module`.

Comment: can't we use this? -> from module import *

Comment: @GayalKuruppu That imports the content of the module, not the module itself.